# NullToVisibilityConverter not being triggered by selection change

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a StackPanel that I would like to hide when there isn't a selected item from a ListView in the same window. Currently, when I open the window, there is no selected item and the StackPanel is hidden, but when I do select something from the ListView, no change occurs.

I am binding the SelectedItem in the ListView like:

```
<ListView
     MinHeight="0"
     MaxHeight="500"
     Margin="10,10,10,0"
     Background="#e7f5f4"
     BorderThickness="0"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIssue}"
     SelectionMode="Single">
```

Where "SelectedIssue" is a custom class property in my ViewModel (my entire window has the same DataContext). I am currently binding the Visibility property of my StackPanel as:

```
<StackPanel
     Grid.Column="1"
     Margin="13,0,0,5"
     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
     Background="#ebf7f6"
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     Visibility="{Binding SelectedIssue, 
     Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter},
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

And my converter is:

```
public class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Here is my getter/setter

```
    private Issue _selectedIssue;
    public Issue SelectedIssue
    {
        get { return _selectedIssue; }
        set { Set(ref _selectedIssue, value); }
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the getter/setter for SelectedIssue? Probably just missing a property changed event for when the SelectedIssue changes. The UI won't know the value has changed unless you tell it...

Comment: Just added. I am raising the event, right?

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in Visual Studio's Output Window when the bindings go in to effect?  Sometimes they are easy to miss.

Comment: @Michael Holvey you are missing the name of the property when calling Set(ref _selectedIssue, value); should be Set(ref _selectedIssue, value, "SelectedIssue");

Answer (score 0):

apparently the problem is that you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` or you not raise (in the SelectedIssue property setter) the `PropertyChanged` Event.

but you can do simpler, binding the `StackPanel` directly to `ListView.SelectedItem`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
     MinHeight="0"
     MaxHeight="500"
     Margin="10,10,10,0"
     Background="#e7f5f4"
     BorderThickness="0"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIssue}"
     SelectionMode="Single">

<StackPanel
     Grid.Column="1"
     Margin="13,0,0,5"
     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
     Background="#ebf7f6"
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listView
     Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}" >
```